How would "Freizeichen" translate to English as opposed to "Wählton"?
How would "Freizeichen" translate to English as opposed to "Wählton"?
I am getting dial tone as the translation for both words.
"Freizeichen" - the tone that indicates, that the line is ready to start dialing 
"Wählton" - the tone that occurs when a digit is dialed

More suited to https://german.stackexchange.com/ ?

I thought that first, but this is a question about English not German.

One needs to know the meaning/usage of the German words to answer it, though! Google Translate gives ringtone for Rufton.

Both are referred to as dial tone in English. It's normally obvious from context, but you can clarify, e.g. DTMF is a common scheme for sounds produced when dialing, and there are various dial tones produced by an exchange depending on the telephone system - do some research on Wikipedia. I suggest you find a forum for elderly telephone engineers to get more information, as neither is used these days when even landline calls are typically routed over IP. Technical questions are generally off-topic when you can consult actual experts for an accurate answer.

@StuartF I wanted a more-known colloquial term, instead of using a word only known by experts. Also, I didn't want to believe, that there aren't separate terms for them, because they are quite different (first needs to be heard before dialing, second reflects dialing from a user perspective), which I thought need to be reflected when talking about it in everyday life.

This answer was written before a change to the question.
Google Translate translates «Freizeichen» as "dial tone", which is the tone you hear when you pick up a telephone but before you dial the number.
It translates «Rufton» as "ring tone", which is what you hear when someone calls you on your mobile phone.
(Links above are to Merriam-Webster online dictionary)
The following material was added after the question was revised and clarified.
Given the usage that you describe for «Wählton», the translation of "dial tone" is incorrect; I would describe them as "Touch-Tone beeps", although I think the technical term is "DTMF Tones" (Link to Wikipedia)

Thanks for the answer, but I was unable to ask the question correctly myself.

@Caulder - see the update to the answer.

@zeitlin So there is no "normal" term for this tones?

@Caulder - "Touch-Tone" started out in the US as a trademark; other companies called it something else. A generic non-technical term for them might be "tone-dialling tones", but most North American speakers of English will recognize "Touch-Tone beeps".

@zeitlin It think I will go with the technical term then. (Actually asked this to name a variable.)

You're far better using a proper German-English dictionary written by a human being than Google Translate. Google Translate tries to make things up, but isn't always right.

@StuartF I am trying to never use Google Translate. In this case, as mentioned in the question, I got the same translation for both words.
